# I cant get wordpress to sort advanced custom field sort by date

Tags: wordpress

Hoi
i have a script, that have to order some post in wordpress. I youe Advanced Custom Fileds. The Field-group is called Kalender, and the date filed is called dato.

I try to order the list by this

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query(
    array('posttype' => 'kalender',
          'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
          'meta_key'=> 'dato',
          'order' => 'DESC'));
```

But that is not sorting the posts after date.

Can anyone tell me that is wrong?

Comment: This should be working. Is your custom date field set to the date picker field type? Could you show your loop code?

Comment: Yes @WizardCoder  the field is a date picker field. The loop goes like this: <?php $custom_query = new WP_Query(array('posttype' => 'kalender','orderby'=> 'meta_value','meta_key'=> 'dato','order' => 'DESC'));



while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); 

// here is the output
       
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: I am not sure what to suggest then. I have recreated your query on my testing wordpress site using the same custom field name and it is ordering correctly.

Comment: Thanks. When I test it, it goes like this: http://angstinfo.dk/kalender/

Comment: You appear to be outputting the post date field, so it is hard to tell if it is ordering by the `dato` field incorrectly. Output the `dato` field just to test if it is definitely outputting in the wrong order.

Comment: I have solved the problem - i got a new webserver :-) Thanks for the comments